# Entity Framework 6 filtered index

Tags: c#, entity-framework, annotations, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I'm developing an application using Entity Framework 6 and I want to use filtered indexes (index with where clause). In Entity Framework there is an `Index` annotation which makes it possible to define an index on a property (column).

I define something like

```
public class SqlDefaultValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public SqlDefaultValueAttribute(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [SqlDefaultValue(123)]
    public int DefInt { get; set; }
}
```

then in `OnModelCreating` function, I write something like this

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<SqlDefaultValueAttribute, object>(nameof(SqlDefaultValueAttribute), (p, attributes) => attributes.Single().Value));
```

and in configuration file something like this

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>{
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    SetSqlGenerator(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, new CustomSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());
}
```

to manipulate SQL generated by EF

For creating a default value at column creation or table creation, I override

```
Generate(CreateTableOperation createTableOperation)
```

and

```
Generate(AddColumnOperation addColumnOperation)
```

In both functions, I can get `AnnotationValue` from `ColumnModel` like this

```
AnnotationValues values;

if (column.Annotations.TryGetValue(nameof(SqlDefaultValueAttribute), out values))
{
    column.DefaultValue = values.NewValue;
}
```

So with set initialize strategy to `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`, every time the model changes, my database changes and default values are set correctly.

Now I want the same thing for index.

How can I define a custom annotation for an index with `AutoMigration` set?

There is an

```
Generate(CreateIndexOperation createIndexOperation)
```

for override, but I don't know how to set `AnonymousArguments` for `createIndexOperation` (`createIndexOperation.Columns` is a list of strings, not `ColumnModel`).

There is some method like manual migration and override `Up` and `Down` functions and override `CreateIndex`, but I want do it done automatically with no manual migration.